# Selenium Python Load Page and Script (Firefox and IE)

Tags: python, performance, selenium, python-webbrowser

I don't really have idea about that so I'd like you to give me some advice if you can.

Generally when I use Selenium I try to search the element that I'm interested in, but now I was thinking to develop some kind of performance test so check how much time take a specific webpage (html, script, etc...) to load.

Do you have some idea how to know the load time of html, script etc without search for a specific element of the page?

PS I use IE or Firefox

Comment: Do you know in advance what the underlying javascript framework is?

Comment: I could know it but I was trying to write a general script for each page and I wanted that selenium wait that load all the page before starting to do something else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check the underlying javascript framework for active connections. When there are no active connections you could then assume the page is finished loading.

That, however, requires that you either know what framework the page uses, or that you must systematically check for different frameworks and then check for connections.

```
def get_js_framework(driver):
    frameworks = [
        'return jQuery.active',
        'return Ajax.activeRequestCount',
        'return dojo.io.XMLHTTPTransport.inFlight.length'
    ]

    for f in frameworks:
        try:
            driver.execute_script(f)
        except Exception:
            logging.debug("{0} didn't work, trying next js framework".format(f))
            continue
        else:
            return f
    else:
        return None


def load_page(driver, link):
    timeout = 5
    begin = time.time()

    driver.get(link)
    js = _get_js_framework(driver)

    if js:
        while driver.execute_script(js) and time.time() < begin + timeout:
            time.sleep(0.25)
    else:
        time.sleep(timeout)
```

Comment: Very good thanks so much ;) Instead how can I check when finish to load all the  HTML? is there something similar?